# Artin-Schreier radicals and cyclic extension

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $p>0$ and $K\subset L$ a cyclic extension of degree $p$.

Prove: We have $L=K(\alpha)$ for a zero of an Artin-Schreier polynomial $f=X^p-X-a\in K[X]$.

Hint: Look at the resolvent $\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}i\sigma^i(x)$ for an element $x\in L$ with trace $1$.

The proof of this theorem for $n=p=char(K)$ goes as follows:

Let $\sigma$ be a generator of $Gal(L/K)$ and $\zeta\in K$ a primitive nth root of unity.

We construct an element $\alpha\in L^*$ with $\sigma(\alpha)=\zeta \alpha$ by looking at:
$$\alpha=x+\zeta^{-1}\sigma(x)+\zeta^{-2}\sigma^2(x)+...+\zeta^{1-n}\sigma^{n-1}(x)$$
where $x\in L$ is chosen such that $\alpha\neq 0$ (it exists by Artin-Dedekind lemma). Then a simple verification gives $\sigma(\alpha)=\zeta \alpha$. The element $a=\alpha^n$ is now in $K$ because $\sigma$ leaves $a$ invariant:
$$\sigma(a)=\sigma(\alpha^n)=\sigma(\alpha)^n=\zeta^n\alpha^n=\alpha^n=a$$
Since $\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta$, repeatedly applying $\sigma$ to the identity $\sigma(\alpha)=\zeta\alpha$ gives $\sigma^i(\alpha)=\zeta^i\alpha$. Therefore the subgroup $Gal(L/K(\alpha))\subset Gal(L/K)$ of powers of $\sigma$ that fix $\alpha$ is the trivial subgroup $<\sigma^n>=1$. Consequently, we have $L=K(\alpha)$ with $\alpha=\sqrt[n]{a}$ a zero of $X^n-a$.

How can we adapt this proof to give the desired result for Artin-Schreier polynomials? I'm not sure how to use the hint, nor how the trace comes into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that the corresponding Galois group of order $p$ of this cyclic extension is $G=\langle \sigma \rangle$.

First of all, using the lemma of Artin-Dedekind such an element $\beta:=\sum^{p-1}_{i=0}i\sigma^i(x) \in L$ for $x \in L$ exists with trace equal to $1$ (after rescaling). Try to show that $L = K(\beta)$ by looking at the way $\sigma$ works on $\beta$ (here you can use that the trace of $x$ is equal to $1$).

Then you show that $\beta$ is a zero of some polynomial $x^p-x-a \in K[x]$ (show that $\beta^p-\beta \in K$).

Comment: You get $\sigma(\beta)=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}i\sigma^{i+1}(x)$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\sigma^{i}(x)=1$, then how can you conclude $L=K(\beta)$? I don’t see it. Also, for the second part, isn’t it true that $\beta^p= \sum_{i=0}^{p-1}i^p\sigma^{ip}(x)=px=0 $? I might be wrong.

Comment: Look at the tower $K \subset K(\beta) \subset L$, where $K \subset L$ is a cyclic extension. Note that $\sigma(\beta) = 0 \cdot \sigma(x) + 1 \cdot \sigma^2(x) + ... + (p-2)\cdot \sigma^{p-1}(x) + (p-1) \cdot x = ... $. Then you see that $\beta \in L$ is not invariant under $\sigma$ (therefore not invariant under $\langle \sigma \rangle$ expect of course the identity), therefore the subgroup corresponding to the field $K(\beta)$ is trivial. Because of Galois theory you can conclude that $K(\beta) = L$.

Comment: For the second part you are wrong. I'm not sure what your reasoning is. But try to show that $\beta^p-\beta$ is invariant under $\sigma$ (therefore invariant under $\langle \sigma \rangle$ ).  And then because of Galois theory you can conclude that $\beta^p-\beta \in K$.

Comment: I think $\beta^p=x+2x^2+…+(p-1)x^{p-1}$. Is that right? Regarding your first comment, I understand everything you’ve said but I don’t get where you proved $\sigma(\beta)\neq \beta$, nor where you used that the trace is 1.

Comment: Well, I claim that $\sigma(\beta) = \beta -1$.

Comment: If you can't manage to prove it by the end of the day, let me know. I will help you.

Comment: I've got it! Thanks so much!! $\sigma(\beta)=\beta-1$, then $\beta\in L$ is not invariant under $<\sigma>$ except the identity, hence the subgroup $Gal(L/K(\beta))\subset Gal(L/K)$ is 1. Then $L=K(\beta)$. Is that right?

Comment: For the second part I've gotten $\beta^p-\beta=x+2x^2+...+(p-1)x^{p-1}-\sigma(x)-\sigma^2(x)-...-(p-1)\sigma^{p-1}(x)$
and 

$\sigma(\beta^p-\beta)=\sigma(x)+\sigma^2(x)+...+\sigma^{p-1}(x)-(p-1)x=1-px=1$, so I think there might be something wrong...?

Comment: Yes, exactly :).

Comment: Note that $\sigma$ is an automorphism, thus $\sigma(\beta^p-\beta) = \sigma(\beta)^p - \sigma(\beta) = ...$ .

Comment: This is so confusing, sorry.
$\beta^p-\beta=x+2x^2+...+(p-1)x^{p-1}-\sigma(x)-2\sigma^2(x)-...-(p-1)\sigma^{p-1}(x)$.
On the other hand, $\sigma(\beta)^p=x^2+2x^3+...+(p-2)x^{p-1}+(p-1)x^p$.
I don't see how this gets to the desired result. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146218/discussion-between-cut-and-anton-odina).